# NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/") Not Working

Tags: blazor

[image]

I have created a Component Base class for add Employee in pages after adding employee details, I want redirect to the list page using `NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/")` but throwing an error:

> Object Null Reference Exception

Even in addEmployee.razor page `NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/employeelist")` is working.

Comment: what's name of your razor file? Can you show me route defined inside your razor file? Make sure your razor file name must be start with uppercase letter (like EmployeeList.razor), not lowercase letter ( not like employeeList.razor).

Comment: remove the static key word.

Comment: Remove the static keyword from NavigationManager. Your routing will work fine after doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the NavigationManager it does not exist or rather is null.

Remove the static key word, and all is fine. This is the cause... Yet, it is preferable that your properties are defined as public rather than protected

Hope this helps...